# Why is the height of a .btn class applied to input, button, and a tags different heights?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've assigned a btn and btn-default class to an input type="submit" in a form and an a-tag with btn btn-default. The button is smaller than the a-tag. What can be the reason? When I compare line-height padding etc. its are the same. What can be the reason? I've assigned display: inline-block to the form.

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

> Cross-browser rendering
>
> As a best practice, we highly recommend using the `<button>` element
>   whenever possible to ensure matching cross-browser rendering.
>
> Among other things, there's a Firefox bug that prevents us from
>   setting the line-height of `<input>-`based buttons, causing them to not
>   exactly match the height of other buttons on Firefox.